# О правильности построения предложений

Tags: недопустимая-метка, грамотная-речь

1. Более двух тысяч домов стоят в воде, в которых до сих пор остаются люди, которые опасаются мародёров.
2. После обеда было принято решение все же использовать тяжелые бомбардировщики Су-34 для бомбардировки ледяного затора.

Хотелось бы услышать экспертное мнение.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Более двух тысяч домов стоят в воде, и в них до сих пор остаются опасающиеся мародёров люди.

В середине дня /для бомбардировки ледяного затора /всё же решили  использовать/  тяжелые бомбардировщики Су-34.

Примечание: Более двух тысяч домов стоят **в воде, в которых**  - союзное слово в СПП желательно располагать после опорного  слова, поэтому использовано ССП.

Answer (score 0):

Порядок слов выглядит как в английском. Если во втором предложении он лишь несколько портит стиль, то в первом он грамматически недопустим (причастный оборот оторван от ключевого слова). Исправить можно так:

> В воде оказалось более двух тысяч домов, в которых до сих пор остаются
>   люди; они опасаются мародёров. В середине дня всё же было принято
>   решение использовать для бомбардировки ледяного затора тяжелые
>   бомбардировщики Су-34.